# Babylon doesn't work with the Internet Explorer browser

Tags: internet-explorer, babylon

I used on Babylon, it always works with Internet Explorer well (when I click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Right Click</kbd>) the Babylon recognizes the word and translates it), but now I try to click but the Babylon window, it doesn't appear, does anyone has a solution for this problem? or know why its occurring?

Comment: Does babylon use a toolbar with internet explorer... is this toolbar still visible? Did you update internet explorer to a new version? It may not work past version 7.

Comment: I dont update, and what you mean on the words "Does babylon use a toolbar with internet explorer... is this toolbar still visible"?

Comment: the program babylon, does it make a bar at the top of Internet Explorer, like the bar in this photo with the words (Translate) (Greencard) (Chinese)? http://www.roysac.com/blogimages/HowtoTurnPayingCustomersintoPirates_C468/babyloniehomepage.png ...Maybe this bar is necessary?

Comment: yes, its necessary, how can I add it?

Comment: what I should do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps stop using internet explorer?

Comment: I think reinstall babylon program, like techie suggests. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try reinstalling/updating [Babylon](http://dictionary.babylon.com/tools/#)?

Answer (score 1):

Babylon doesn't support IE9 yet. Switch off Clear Type within Windows as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your Internet Explorer browser.
2. Go to *Tools*.
3. *Internet Options*.
4. *Security*.
5. Uncheck *Enable Protected mode*.
6. Restart you computer.

Be aware your computer will be at risk.